# Limit the length of QStringList when printing

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to limit the length of my message when using a QStringList by printing only the first five strings.

Here is my implementation:

```
// QStringList missing is already filled with random strings
QString warning = "Missing: ";
// Limit the warning up to the fifth element
for ( int i = 0; i < missing.size(); ++i ) {
    if ( i <= 4 ) {
        warning += ", %1".arg( missing.at(i) );
    } else {
        warning += ", ...";
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the guidance of hauron I found that this may be the most efficient way:

```
if ( !missing.empty() ) { 
  auto noOfPrintStr = 5;
  QString warning = tr( "Missing: %1" )
                    .arg( missing.mid( 0, noOfPrintStr-1 ).join( ", " ) );
  if ( missing.size() > noOfPrintStr )
    warning += ", ...";

  // print the warning
}
```

Comment: Nice, altho it doesn't say in the docs whether it does involve deep or shallow copying of list elements. You could check it in the Qt sources, if you really care ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper:

```
QString joinWithLimit(size_t lenLimit, const QStringList &strings, const QString &separator = ", ")
{
    QString result;
    result.reserve(lenLimit); // to reduce number of allocations
    result += strings.front();

    for (int i = 1; i < strings.size(); ++i)
    {
       const auto &s = strings[i];
       if (result.length() + separator.length() + s.length() > lenLimit) {
           return result;
       }
       result += separator;
       result += s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you need performance then use of `arg` is not recommended (it need to do extra job of parsing format string and you do not control allocations).

Answer (score -1):

Try using `QStringList::join(...)` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#join).

Since you want to merge only up to first 5 elements, to avoid copying the list, use iterators, i.e.:

```
QString foo(const QStringList& myList)
{
   auto iterBegin = myList.begin();
   auto iterEnd = iterBegin + std::min(myList.size(), 5);
   return QStringList{iterBegin, iterEnd}.join(", ");
}
```

... but it wouldn't work, as `QStringList` does not have such a constructor. You'd have to copy the `QStrings` into a new `QStringList`. Ideally, the copies would be shallow - the buffer is shared between the two `QStrings` in two different `QStringLists`, but I'm not sure if Qt does it this way (it may, and provide a separate buffer only if you try to change the underlying string).

Either way, once you've got your `QStringList` being a sublist, just invoke:

```
subList.join(", ");
```

Comment: this was exactly my problem that there is no such a constructor because as you are saying the best option is to use join through a sublist.

Comment: I found how we can get a sublist from a qlist: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#mid
So now we can have the sublist and use join.

Comment: To the person downvoting, may I ask why the downvote?